# Fill the missing value using comparing other column in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Need to fill the missing value.

| Product | Another |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| A | Nan |
| B | Nan |
| B | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| B | Nan |
| B | Nan |
| c | 5 |
| C | 5 |

Output needs as below:

| Product | Another |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| c | 5 |
| C | 5 |

If the product is A, the value should be 3 and for B, it is 4.
is it possible to  add using fillna?

Comment: `df.groupby('Product')['Another'].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
`?

Comment: I changed the data set again. can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for records where "Product" is `A` and "Another" is missing. Same for "Product" `B`. By that you arrive at the following code naturally:

```
idx_missing = df["Another"] == np.nan
idx_missing_A = idx_missing & df["Product"] == 'A'
idx_missing_B = idx_missing & df["Product"] == 'B'

df.loc[idx_missing_A, "Another"] = 3
df.loc[idx_missing_B, "Another"] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 3,4 are just the first values for that letter-group, so you can access them with `.groupby()...head()`

But for more general cases you could use `df['Product'].map({'A':3, 'B':4})` to get the series of replacement values, then fillna it with

```
df['Another'].fillna(df['Product'].map({'A':3, 'B':4}))
```